# How can i get all the user documents from a collection in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named flpProduct in firestore. I want to access all the documents stored in the flpProduct collection. I tried it with many Futurebuilder and Streambuilder but none of them worked.

I tried this

```
 FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot> (
        future: flpProductFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text('Something went Wrong'),
            );
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
              snapshot.hasData) {
            snapshot.data.documents.forEach((element) {
              print(element.data['title']);
            });
            return Text('done');
          }

          return Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Spinner(),
              Text(
                'Fetching Data',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 18.0),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
```

This seems to get me the data but how can i now display this in a widget.
I already have a class that returns a container to display the information in a seperate class. I just want to pass the data to the class and display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use StreamBuilder rather than FutureBuilder
because StreamBuilder is responsible for real-time changes

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(Your collection Name).snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document.data()[key]),
              subtitle: new Text(document.data()[key]),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
```